# Accounts to Contacts in SUGARCRM

Tags: php, model-view-controller, sugarcrm

I am new to sugar and need to have each Account tied to one Contact, the same way that each Lead is linked to a Contact and Account.  I have already changed the metadata file to make Account:Contact a 1:1 relationship but past that I am not sure what to do.  I would like to ultimately be able to view the contact name for each account when I go to view Accounts as well as be able to import Accounts from a file with a contact field.

I am using Sugar Community Edition 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the existing contacts module, a suggestion would be to add a new field (e.g. called `account_contact`) to the accounts module. That way it would be easy to change the account list view to include the new field, and also include it in the account search options.

I don't think I fully understand you import requirement, but it is possible to set all account fields during the import. So the newly added field is also available in the import.

If you don't want the default Sugar contacts module, you can disable this in the adminstration.

Comment: this is OK for a solution but i already have contact instances linked to account instances so i would have to write a script to look up the contact name for each account and insert it into the new field.  it might come to that but if possible i rather modify sugar to lookup the name field for every account's contact, and also generate an account AND contact instance from my import table, the same way that when you convert a lead it generates an account and contact

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into sub-panels at all? Your contact information is always associated with the Account in the detail view--> contacts sub-panel. You want to keep only one contact per account? Create a relate field in the studio FROM CONTACTS to accounts. A one to one account field will appear in contacts and account will have a one to one sub-panel. you can reverse this just by creating this relate field in ACCOUNTS instead. A word of advice - don't start messing with the metadata until you fully understand the relationships built into sugar.